# python shell restart when trying to restart a script

Tags: python

I have been coding a program that opens files and edits them, but for the code to do what needs to be done it has to auto reset itself, I've spent a while browsing the interwebs for some help but can't seem to find anyone else asking this question. The code I attempted to use to restart was probably terribly off:

```
os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, * sys.argv)
```

any help is appreciated.

```
import os

PassCount = 0
SetUp = 0

newpath = r"PassEncryptPY"
if not os.path.exists(newpath):
    os.makedirs(newpath)

f = open("PassEncryptPY/PassEncryptPY_PTF.txt", "a")
g = open("PassEncryptPY/PassEncryptPY_ETF.txt", "a")

if os.path.getsize(r"PassEncryptPY/PassEncryptPY_PTF.txt") == 0:
    print("we have detected that you dont have a password")
    pas = input("Your password: ")
    f.write(pas)
    SetUp = SetUp + 1

if os.path.getsize(r"PassEncryptPY/PassEncryptPY_ETF.txt") == 0:
    print("we have detected that you dont have a email")
    ema = input("Your email: ")
    g.write(ema)
    SetUp = SetUp + 1

if SetUp != 0:
    print("Set Up complete, restarting")
    f.flush()
    g.flush()
    os.fsync(f.fileno())
    os.fsync(g.fileno())
    import sys
    os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, * sys.argv)

f.close()
g.close()
```

Comment: you are missing a ton of relevant details ... but that command looks reasonable ... we have no idea what went wrong you didnt even give us a traceback or how you launched the program or anything

Comment: It restarts the python shell but not the code itself.

Comment: I stripped this down to [a quick test](https://gist.github.com/abarnert/8129a96f0022c2b86071297dc961d1d4), and it seems to do exactly what you want, as you'd expect—it prints 'Hi!' every second until you kill it.

Comment: However, depending on your platform and Python version, if the script isn't in the current working directory, `sys.argv[0]` might not be enough to run it. Any chance that's your problem? If you don't know, try printing out `__FILE__`, `sys.argv[0]`, and `os.getcwd()` right before the `execl`.

Comment: Also, what do you mean "It restarts the python shell but not the code itself"? What exactly happens that makes you think Python restarted but your code didn't?

Comment: Better, give us an [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that prints out some different output from what you expected/wanted, so you can just show us the difference.

Answer (score 1):

`sys.executable` is not what you expect probably. (assuming you run the script with `./some_name.py` rather than `python ./some_name.py`) It will almost always be the interpreter rather than the script you're running.

You probably wanted something like:

```
own_name = sys.argv[0]
os.execl(own_name, own_name, *sys.argv[1:])
```

Print your `sys.executable` and `sys.argv` to see the difference.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `sys.executable` is exactly what he's expecting it to be. His code will exec, e.g., `python myscript.py myarg myarg`, which is exactly what it should be doing.

Comment: @abarnert added an explanation about which way the script it called - I think it addresses what you're thinking of

Comment: But even if the script is called with `./some_name.py`, calling it with `python some_name.py` (as long as you use the right Python in the shbang line—which you will, because that's what will be in `sys.executable`), it will still do the right thing. His version works for _both_ `./some_name.py` and `python some_name,py` (and also `pypy3.5 some_name.py` and so on); yours only works for the first one.